# Git error message "remote origin already exists"

Tags: git, github

I created a repo on github, then tried to connect to it and got this error:

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

This did not happen yesterday when I created a different repo. Can anyone help me figure out how to push to this existing repo on gibash? I'm a total newbie!

Answer (score 3):

First:
`git remote remove origin`

Second:
`git remote add origin https://(token)@github.com/username/repository-name`

Last:
`git push`

It always works for me. If not, I realized that I made mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting `remote origin already exist` is because a remote by the name of `origin` already exists. You can check by typing `git remote -v` which will show you all the remotes of your git repo. You should see this:

```
origin  https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git (push)
```

The command to clone your github repo is `git clone https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git <folder_name>`. If you do that a remote called `origin` would be automatically setup for you, therefore you do not need to add `https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git` as a remote manually by typing `git remote add origin https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git`.

The case in which you would need to type `git remote add origin https://github.com/jatalamo/heroku-test-site.git` is when you are not cloning from github but instead you typed `git init` on your local machine and there is not remote, so you'll have to manually add the github url as a remote called `origin` or whatever other name you like.

You should be able to then pull and push using these commands:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

Comment: I did remote -v and all it shows is a previously created repo named rutgers. The heroku-test-site is not showing???

Comment: sorry im a bit confused. what is the previously created repo? are you in the correct folder when typing the git command? if possible update your question with some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I figured it out. Removing ".git" from the end on the URL worked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Open up `.git/config` and manually change the url of the remote repository under `[remote "origin"]`. Then try it again.